# How to avoid or bypass setup code alert (popup) in HomeKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit

I am working on HomeKit enable application.

In that while adding accessory to home, I want to avoid setup code popup.

By default apple provides its own alert in which we have to enter setup code while adding accessory with Home.

Edit : More info
To add accessory in home we need to call `addAccessory` method of `HMHome` class.
currently iOS automatically manages the authentication of accessory by showing setup code popup (that code can be found on Accessory box).

My requirement is to bypass that setup code popup and directly pass code for authentication.

Below is the method `addAccessory`: which is used to add accessory to home.

```
[self.currentHome addAccessory:thisAccessory completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [self showError:error];
    }
    else {
        // Accessory Added
    }
}];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not very detailed. Please add some more information so it's easier for us to understand your issue and help you out. What have you tried? Where does it go wrong? Share some code with us!

Comment: I don't believe that you can avoid that popup.  It is part of the security in HomeKit

Comment: Confirming that you cannot skip this. It is a system prompt initiated by the call to `- addAccessory:completionHandler:`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide to access this screen. You don't have any control for this Setup code Popup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.